# How can I get the directly connected bus stops to a certain bus stop using openstreetmap?

Tags: graph, gis, openstreetmap

Currently I am working on a project and I want to create a graph for certain city where the nodes are the bus stops and the edges are the routes between the bus stops.
I am able to get the whole city bus stops using openstreetmap but I don't know How to get the set of bus stops which directly connected to a certain bus stops.
Any Ideas or suggestions?

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/46848/how-can-i-get-the-directly-connected-bus-stops-to-a-certain-bus-stop-using-openstreetmap

Answer (score 2):

Such connections are represented in OSM by [relations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation), particularly [route relations](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:route). Currently there are two different [public transport](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Public_transport) schemes in use. This could make a difference for you, depending on the exact information you are going to extract. The version might be indicated by the [public_transport:version](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:public%20transport:version) key, but doesn't necessarily have to.

Here are some examples:

- [bus relation using the old pulbic transport scheme](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/5351356)
- [bus relation using the new pulbic transport scheme](http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/721888)

Comment: but how can I get the bus stops which I can reach them all from a specific bus stops  directly without passing through another bus stops

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. For identifying which other bus stops can be reached from a specific bus stop you just have to look through all the relations this bus stop is a member of.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an [example](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/cZ9) following scai's answer, using Overpass API. It assumes that the [new public transport scheme](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Proposed_features/Public_Transport) used for the routes and stops data.

Comment: Yep ,it is gave me the whole bus stops in bbox,but my question was for given bus stop what is the set of bus stops which can be reached from there directly (no bus stop in between )

Comment: If you don't "unzoom" from the area show in overpass by default, it gets the stop visible in the bbox, and all stops directly reacheable without connections. 
By "no stop inbetween", do you mean only the first stop of each line departing from the bbox ?

Comment: consider the following scenario a bus stop A there are two routes L1 L2 if I take the bus from A on route L1 the first bus stop come immediately is B and the same if i take the bus  on L2 the first bus stop comes is C ,So I need a way to get B and C bus stops if I give you I am on Bus stop A is it clear now ?

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do that without post-processing the Overpass API response.